# Dynamic COUNTIFS - No INDIRECT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, excel-indirect

I have a COUNTIFS statement that dynamically gets the row to count in, which works fine, but I have a small problem with it that I'd like to see if there was a way to fix:

```
=COUNTIFS(locplan_week,AU$20, INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Tracker!G",$C56,":UK",$C56)), "B")
```

*$C56 refers to a cell where I have found the row number via a MATCH.*

As I said works fine, until someone inserts a column into the Tracker sheet. So am looking for a way to do this without INDIRECT, and where Excel would then take care of adjusting the Column indicator for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX to replace your INDIRECT.

```
=COUNTIFS(locplan_week, AU$20, INDEX('Tracker'!G:UK, $C56, 0), "B")
```

I'm assuming that the orientation and size of locplan_week and a single row within 'Tracker'!G:UK is the same.

Comment: @tomm if this worked please mark as correct as it will reward Jeeped and remove this from the unanswered queue.

Comment: Done .. was looking for where to do so ... missing the giant check mark staring me in the face